CORS policy error and websocket errors with Apache, node.js, socket.io on Ubuntu Server
I have a Linux (Ubuntu) server running Apache2. I've deployed a chat application built with Node.js, Socket.io, and React.js. The application includes three domains: admin, client, and backend.
When accessing the admin side I got the errors:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at
'https://[backend-domain]/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P1Ft1S6'
from origin 'https://[admin-domain]' has been blocked by CORS
policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
requested resource. GET
https://[backend-domain]/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P1Ft1S6
net::ERR_FAILED 500 (Internal Server Error) Connection error: Error:
xhr poll error

The backend Node.js application logs errors:

No protocol handler was valid for the URL /socket.io/ (scheme 'ws').
If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy
submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.,
referer: https://[client-domain]/

Here is my backend apache config file Apache config File image
apache2ctl configtest returns oky and ports are correctly configured
For CORS I have following code in my server.js (Backend)
Server.js Backend File code
I have ensured the Apache config syntax is correct. The ports are configured properly but however I'm getting the CORS and Websocket errors. I have also attached the SSL.
I hope to overcome the CORS error and WebSocket connection error
